# Can you await firebase cloud auth.user().OnCreate function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Any time user registers, cloud function will create a new user object in the realtime database. The problem is, that I need to access user data right after firebase.auth().signIn().then() but onCreate invokes earlier than then() statement.

Is there any way to await auth.user().onCreate method in firebase.auth().signIn()?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you check my answer? After user has registered, it will create data in real-time database and using another onCreate from your app it will fetch the data. Please post your app code. After registration force user to logout which will give time for your app to fetch data.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible.  There can only be one triggering event for a Cloud Function, and it can't be changed.

If you have a function that creates some data in Realtime Database, and you want the client app to wait for that data to be created, all you need to do is add a listener at the location of the expected data.  For example, if the data is being created using the UID of the newly created user (say, `/user/{uid}`), all you have to do is build the path to that data in the same way the function would do it, add the listener, and continue your app's UI after the listener triggers.  You can certainly listen to data that doesn't exist yet.

It's similar to what I've written here in [this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07), except it's using Firestore instead of Realtime Database, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: Looks like he want something to run when a new Auth is generated?

Comment: @Dharmaraj No, I think they want the client to read the database data generated by the function as soon as it's created.

Comment: Let's see. Atleast using `functions.auth.user().onCreate` will prevent his issue. Thereafter he can use `onCreate()` on that particular path to fetch data instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add this is your Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
export const onNewUserAuth = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    //To get user Auth Credentials add below code:
    const newUserUID = user.uid
    const newUserEmail = user.email

    //Add Data to Realtime Database this way
    return admin.database().ref(<your-path-here>).update({ "UID": newUserUID })

})
```

Now if you want to get the data immediately after user is created and the info is stored in database. Use another `onCreate()` to get the data. But remember this is going to cost you another function invocation.